# How to quickly delete a wallpaper in OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, desktop-customization

In OSX I have it setup so that the wallpaper is set to a directory with various images and it changes automatically. Sometimes an image will come up and it's one that I'd like to delete. What's a quick way to delete it without having to try to find out which image it is?

Answer (score 4):

The `Dock` process is responsible for changing the desktop wallpaper based on the settings in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist` among these the key `ChangePath` (or `NewChangePath`) used to determine from which folder to take the image.

But there is no persistent copy made of that image file, or a reference to it, you could use.

---

Your only option then is to rely on the file system metadata: Since the `Dock` process needs to access the files that are to be displayed, you can pick the N most recently accessed files from that folder.

A command-line call that accomplished this would be e.g.

```
stat -f "%a:%N" /Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Nature/* | sort | tail -n3 | cut -d: -f2
```

Change the argument to `tail` to however many most recently accessed images you want listed. The most recently (i.e. hopefully current) image is the last one listed.

Since your filesystem records accesses of *any* program, this will probably start failing as soon as you e.g. view the folder in Finder, have it open in iPhoto, or use QuickLook to view some of the images.